# Why doesn't anyone care about this MySQLdb bug? is it a bug?

Tags: python, deadlock, mysql

TL;DR: I've supplied a patch for a bug I found and I've got 0 feedback on it. I'm wondering if it's a bug at all. This is not a rant. Please read this and if you may be affected by it check the fix.

I have found and reported this MySQLdb bug some weeks ago (edit: 6 weeks ago), sent a patch, posted it on a couple of ORM's forums, mailed the MySQLdb author, mailed some people talking about handling deadlocks, mailed ORM authors and I'm still waiting for any kind of feedback.

This bug caused me a lot of grief and the only explanations I can find on the feedback is that either no one uses "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" in python with mysql or that this is not a bug.

Basically the problem is that deadlocks and "lock wait timeout" exceptions are NOT being raised when issuing a "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" using a MySQLdb cursor.
Instead, the statement fails silently and returns an empty resultset, which any application will interpret as if there were no rows matched.

I've tested the SVN version and it's still affected. Tested on the default installations of Ubuntu Intrepid, Jaunty and Debian Lenny and those are affected too. The current version installed by easy_install (1.2.3c1) is affected.

This affects SQLAlchemy and SQLObject too and probably any ORM that used MySQLdb cursors is affected too.

This script can reproduce a deadlock that will trigger the bug (just change the user/pass in get_conn, it will create the necessary tables):

```
import time
import threading
import traceback
import logging
import MySQLdb

def get_conn():
    return MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', db='TESTS',
                           user='tito', passwd='testing123')

class DeadlockTestThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, order):
        super(DeadlockTestThread, self).__init__()
        self.first_select_done = threading.Event()
        self.do_the_second_one = threading.Event()
        self.order = order

    def log(self, msg):
        logging.info('%s: %s' % (self.getName(), msg))

    def run(self):
        db = get_conn()
        c = db.cursor()
        c.execute('BEGIN;')
        query = 'SELECT * FROM locktest%i FOR UPDATE;'
        try:
            try:
                c.execute(query  % self.order[0])
                self.first_select_done.set()

                self.do_the_second_one.wait()
                c.execute(query  % self.order[1])
                self.log('2nd SELECT OK, we got %i rows' % len(c.fetchall()))

                c.execute('SHOW WARNINGS;')
                self.log('SHOW WARNINGS: %s' % str(c.fetchall()))
            except:
                self.log('Failed! Rolling back')
                c.execute('ROLLBACK;')
                raise
            else:
                c.execute('COMMIT;')
        finally:
            c.close()
            db.close()


def init():
    db = get_conn()

    # Create the tables.
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS locktest1;')
    c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS locktest2;')
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE locktest1 (
                    a int(11), PRIMARY KEY(a)
                  ) ENGINE=innodb;''')
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE locktest2 (
                    a int(11), PRIMARY KEY(a)
                  ) ENGINE=innodb;''')
    c.close()

    # Insert some data.
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute('BEGIN;')
    c.execute('INSERT INTO locktest1 VALUES (123456);')
    c.execute('INSERT INTO locktest2 VALUES (123456);')
    c.execute('COMMIT;')
    c.close()

    db.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    init()

    t1 = DeadlockTestThread(order=[1, 2])
    t2 = DeadlockTestThread(order=[2, 1])

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    # Wait till both threads did the 1st select.
    t1.first_select_done.wait()
    t2.first_select_done.wait()

    # Let thread 1 continue, it will get wait for the lock 
    # at this point.
    t1.do_the_second_one.set()

    # Just make sure thread 1 is waiting for the lock.
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # This will trigger the deadlock and thread-2 will
    # fail silently, getting 0 rows.
    t2.do_the_second_one.set()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

The output of running this on an unpatched MySQLdb is this:

```
$ python bug_mysqldb_deadlock.py
INFO:root:Thread-2: 2nd SELECT OK, we got 0 rows
INFO:root:Thread-2: SHOW WARNINGS: (('Error', 1213L, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'),)
INFO:root:Thread-1: 2nd SELECT OK, we got 1 rows
INFO:root:Thread-1: SHOW WARNINGS: ()
```

You can see that Thread-2 got 0 rows from a table we know has 1 and only issuing a "SHOW WARNINGS" statement you can see what happened. 
If you check "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS" you will see this line in the log "*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)", everything that happens after the failing select on Thread-2 is on a half rolled back transaction.

After applying the patch (check the ticket for it, url below), this is the output of running the script:

```
$ python bug_mysqldb_deadlock.py
INFO:root:Thread-2: Failed! Rolling back
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/threading.py", line 442, in __bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "bug_mysqldb_deadlock.py", line 33, in run
    c.execute(query  % self.order[1])
  File "/home/koba/Desarollo/InetPub/IBSRL/VirtualEnv-1.0-p2.4/lib/python2.4/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.2-py2.4-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 178, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/koba/Desarollo/InetPub/IBSRL/VirtualEnv-1.0-p2.4/lib/python2.4/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.2-py2.4-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')

INFO:root:Thread-1: 2nd SELECT OK, we got 1 rows
INFO:root:Thread-1: SHOW WARNINGS: ()
```

In this case an exception is raised on Thread-2 and it rolls back properly.

So, what's your opinion?, is this a bug? no one cares or am I just crazy?

This is the ticket I opened on SF: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2776267&group_id=22307&atid=374932

Comment: +1 for your good bug report description

Comment: I hardly see how a SO question can help here. If you have a working patch, good for you, use it. But don't forget that OSS devs have a real job, a private life, and sometimes it just takes time to treat bug backlogs. The owner got notified when you submitted a bugreport, he saw the notification. Imho the more you're complaining, the less the perspective of fixing the said bug will look appealing to him. Just be patient. And even if he fixes this in one month, say thanks.

Comment: I did not send the same person more than 1 message on this topic. Instead of doing that I asked different persons and the reason I'm asking here is to avoid asking to the same people I already did. I supplied a fix and I would love some feedback from someone with authority on this matter to know if it's ok or not.

Comment: You might want to change the title to : `Apparent Bug in MySQLdb`, provide code that shows the problem.  Then answer your own question with a link to your patch kit.  That would be an SO question/answer.  And anyone with a different/better patch could provide an actual answer.  They "why doesn't anyone care?" question is unanswerable.

Comment: Actually the "why doesn't anyone care?" question can be answered. If this is actually not a real bug then this would be an explanation - and that is what the author was apparently wondering about.

Comment: you aren't the first to complain about the maintenance of mysqldb: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2009/1/8/the-sad-state-of-mysql-python . I have heard rumors that Sun is working on a pure-python alternative to the current c lib based mysqldb

Comment: The project is kinda dead. The last release was two years ago.

Comment: ever get any resolution?

Comment: One of the project admins took the ticket but there were no updates. The patch I attached on the ticket works-for-me, it has been on production for a while.

Comment: to "finish" this question, you could select my answer as "correct", click on the check mark in my question, you'll get 2 points

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why doesn’t anyone care about this
>   MySQLdb bug?

bugs can take a while to prioritize, research, verify the problem, find a fix, test the fix, make sure the fix fix does not break anything else.  I would suggest you deploy a work around, since it could take some time for this fix to arrive for you.

Comment: I still dont't understand the lack of feedback (0, this is in fact the first response I ever got on this topic). It really feels like no one has read it. I'm currently using the patch I uploaded to the ticket which "worksforme".

Comment: Interestingly, though his bug was reported since 2009-04-20. Someone should reply at least!